# how to interpret calculation of the cost for a softmax function

Tags: neural-network, ipython, softmax

I'm struggeling how to interpret/to use the calculation of the log_likelihood when using the softmax activation function in last layer of my neural network. I'm working on a vectorised way. I want to recognize labels from 0 to 9!

```
log_likelihood = -np.log(p[range(m),(Y)])
cost = np.sum(log_likelihood) / m
```

Let's say p = 10(classes) x 103(examples) matrix

m is total examples (103)

Y should be I'll guess the label vector (not one hot vector) = 1 x 103
So Y is something like (1 3 8 7 0 ... 4 1 2 9) in case I want to recognize digits from 0 to 9

So how works the calculation of the log_likelihood? Can somebody explain with an example?
I struggling with the `[range(m),(Y)]` part, I don't know which index is used for each itteration.
Because Y = (1 3 8 7 0 ... 4 1 2 9) and not just for example 1 or 3 or 8 etc...

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have your actual implementation, I will assume that `log_likelihood = -np.log(p[range(m),(Y)]` is a proper format.
In this case, your number of rows is m i.e. 103 and the number of columns will be 10 with each row indicating softmax output with probabilities for each input example.

With range(m), you are 'looping' through m rows. (Not exactly looping in vectorized implementation.)

With mentioning column index as (Y), you are only fetching probability value from softmax output(each row), which indicates the model's outcome for the desired number.

For example, if you wanted the model to detect a number to be 3 then you're only checking how model did on softmax output that should have had high probability value on the index representing value 3. You can look at the example below for intuitive understanding:

```
Y = (0,1,2)
y = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,34,5,6],[1,2,0,4,5]]
print(np.array(y)[range(3),(Y)])
#-----------------------------------------
output: [1 2 0]
```

What you'll get in `log_likelihood` is a vector that is representing the negative log-likelihood cost for softmax units which should have been predicted with high probability.

Comment: I do not understand it completely. You say if you wanted the model to detect a number to be 3, then you're only checking how model did on softmax output... etc... but possible values are only Y=(0,1,2) ? Or Am I incorrect? Also when I use print(np.array(2)[range(3),(Y)]) then I have a shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)  Can you clarify litle bit more? why is np.array(1) and np.array(3) working but not with 2? I'll guess I need litle bit more explanation...

Comment: What I really want is just an example of how log_likelihood = -np.log(p[range(m),(Y)]) is calculated. Maybe with simplified examples. Lets say p = 2 examples x 3 classes, m = 2 and y = [0 1 2] So, what should be likelihood?